# How to change Graphic API from Unity of IOS?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, graphics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvz1G.png)

In the Android option, OpenGl could be selected by turning off the Auto Graphic API.
However, IOS does not have the API op line.

Unity is using 2021.1.13f.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenGl is deprecated in IOS 12 and above.

Comment: Can't I use the target API when it's IOS 11?

Comment: @Kim.JS IOS 11 is 4 years old at this point so I have no ideas regarding it.

Comment: ok, Thank you for answering.